# i want to save and retrive all contacts to Firebase Firestore, need structure to save and retrive contacts

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-contacts

I am developing an app, there's a functionality to get all the contacts of the user and upload it to server. Here I'm using Firebase Firestore as my backend. I can able to get all contacts without duplicates. Can someone please help, in which document structure I need to save the contact details of the user? Please tell me appropriate format so that it wont take much space in Firestore.

And then..

Once all the contacts are saved, I must be able to get the name of a contact using number what user is entering. This is my requirement. in short I would like to know how to save 2500 contact details for Firestore and how to read single contact name with help of contact number what user types in the edittext. (note : I heard like we cant save 2500 contact details of the user in one shot, something like batch should be used)

[image]

I tried this below code but it is saving only first 800 contacts only.

```
`private void doUploadContactstoCloud() {
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait we are configuring your request ...");
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.show();
        listContacts = new ContactPresenter(this).fetchAllContacts();
        int j = listContacts.size();

        Log.d("sizejhfg",j+"");

        double size = listContacts.size();
        double ind = 0;
        Map<String, Object> contact = new HashMap<>();
        // Get a new write batch
        WriteBatch batch = db.batch();
        for (Contact con : listContacts) {
            for (int i = 0; i < con.numbers.size(); i++) {
                String number = formatnum(con.numbers.get(i).number);
                if (number != null) {
                    if (!number.equals("0") && number.length() < 5) {

                        Map<String, Object> contactnumber = new HashMap<>();
                        contactnumber.put("name", con.name);
                        contactnumber.put("number", number);
                        contact.put(number,contactnumber);
                        DocumentReference item = db.collection(tonumber).document(number);
                        batch.set(item,contactnumber);
                        ind++;
                        if(ind==500){
                            doCommit(batch);
                            batch=db.batch();
                            ind=0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //dialog.setProgress((int) (ind / size) * 100);
        }
        if(ind>0){
            doCommit(batch);
        }
        prefManager.setisContactUpload(true);
        doDismissDialog();
    }`
```

1. Please tell how I should save data in Firestore (structure)
2. please tell me to read single contact name with help of number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Please tell how I should save data in Firestore (structure)

If you are using authentication, a possible database schema for you app use-case might be:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
        |
        --- uid (document)
             |
             --- // user properties
             |
             --- contacts (subcollection)
                   |
                   --- contactId (document)
                         |
                         --- phoneNumber: 123456789
                         |
                         --- // other contact properties
```

To get all contacts a user has, simply attach a listener on contacts reference:

```
db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("contacts");
```

> 2. please tell me to read single contact name with help of number

To get the details of single contact having the phone number, please use the following query:

```
db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("contacts").whereEqualTo("phoneNumber", 123456789);
```

According to the official documentation regarding the [maximum number of documents that can be added in single batch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions):

> Each transaction or batch of writes can write to a maximum of 500 documents.

So you have to split your contacts in parts of 500 documents in order to be able to add all those contacts to Firestore.

**Edit:**

> if I assume one user is having 4000 contacts in his phone (just mobile number and name*4000 = 8000 data from a single user).

That's incorrect, if you have only 2 properties (within a contact document), you'll only have 4000 write operations and **not** 8000 because both properties are apart of the same document. So you must write them together using a batch write or using a POJO class.

> if the number of users become 5 million then it will be huge data that needs to be stored on in the Firestore.

That's correct but in the same time it means that you'll have a very successful application and you can afford all those write operations. 5 million believe me, it's much.

> so I want a schema which must the best which should accommodate less space as possible

The problem is not about the space, the problem is about the number of reads and writes you perform. Evrything in Firestore is about the number of reads and writes.

> I am expecting a very efficient way to save data. please help

In my optinion, the schema above can you help you solve the problem.

> considering this still your answer is the best solution?

Considering your request from your question and comments, yes.

> is it possible to ignore uid, contact id and can just have only these parameters

Only if you use [Firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), which is a different product. There are no collections and documents, just a JSON database structure.

Comment: it is going to lots of data that I have to save to Firestore becase for example a if I assume one user is having 4000 contacts in his phone (just mobile number and name*4000 = 8000 data from a single user). if the number of users become 5 million then it will be huge data that needs to be stored on in the Firestore. so I want a schema which must the best which should accommodate less space as possible, I am expecting a very efficient way to save data. please help , nothing I am going to do other than just saving and retrieving of data. considering this still your answer is the best solution?

Comment: is it possible to ignore uid, contact id and can just have only these parameters(
root  
                user1mobilenumber  (name-number)
                                                  (name-number)……..

                user2mobilenumber  (name-number)
                                                  (name-number)……..

                user1mobilenumber  (name-number)
                                                  (name-number)……..

like this?

and when I what to read, i'll pass usermobile2 and number,
from which I need name .

Comment: Please see my updated answer with details for all your questions in the comments.

Comment: definitely I got it but as per this requirement what will be the best one to use..Realtime DB or Firestore? please update. thanks for your valuable information's and spending your time in clarifying my doubts. I guess when I use realttime db , it is not possible to query the name with mobile number because 2 levels of queries involved in this.

Comment: It  depends of the use-case of your app. See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) and [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/cloud-firestore-for-rtdb-developers.html). Regarding that query, it depends. So you're very welcome, cheers!

Comment: I'm finding difficulties! :| my requirement is, when user ABC install the app it will take all the contacts of the user and save to firebase. And when another user XYZ installs the app, it will take all contacts of XYZ and save to firebase. Now my read operation should be, Mr. ABC will type XYZ number in EditText and in firebase, I have to look into XYZ contact details and find out ABC's number and get the name in which XYZ saved in his contact. So when ABC type XYZ number, ABC can able to find out in which name XYZ saved ABC's number.

Comment: Is your answer is still same? If so please let me know how can I save different user contact numbers? Exact coding also would be very very helpful 

Comment: @AndroidManifester This sounds as another use-case so please post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I have added a new question , please help :)

Comment: I have posted different question .. Please help :)

Comment: I have added bounty to my new question .. please try